# How to convert a text file into binary and vice versa?

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I have made the previous problem simpler to get the answer and understand it completely.

The problem is that I want to write a C++ program that converts an ordinary text file into binary and then reads that binary file and converts it to a text file so that this text file equals to first text file. 
I have wrote this simple code for it.

```
int main()
{

      string name1 = "first", name2 = "sec", name3 = "third";
      int j = 0, k = 0;

      ifstream ifs(name1.c_str()); // Here I want to read from the ordinary text file (name1).
      ifs >> j; // Now j equals to 5 because name1 contains digit 5.
      ifs.close();

      ofstream ofs(name2.c_str(), ios::binary);
      ofs.write(as_bytes(j), sizeof(int)); // Here I want to write that j to name2 file in binary mode.                      
      ofs.close();

      ifstream ifs1(name2.c_str(), ios::binary); // Here I want to read from that binary file (name2).
      ifs.read(as_bytes(k), sizeof(int)); // Here I hope k becomes 5.

      ofstream ofs1(name3.c_str());
      ofs1 << k; // Here I want to write that k to name3 file in ordinary text mode.

      ifs1.close();
      ofs1.close();
      // Now I hope both name1 and name2 contain 5.

      keep_window_open();
      return 0;
}
```

Now what the `ofs.write(as_bytes(j), sizeof(int));` or `ifs.read(as_bytes(k), sizeof(int));` exactly means?

**My question is why**, in practice, the file `name1` contains digit 5 and its size is 1 byte. The `name2` contains some character/sign like `[]` and its size is 4 bytes and `name3` contains digit 0 and its size is 1 byte?

I'll completely appreciate your responses.

Please don't extent the issue by giving extra info and only think around this problem. I want to just understand it. (My machine is Windows 7 32-bit. My compiler is MVS 2012. And if any more info is needed just tell me.)

Comment: I before have created the name1 file in ordinary text file mode.

Comment: Hi @NonLinearIdeas (editor of this post), I notice you make a lot of edits (mainly tag additions) to questions that don't really add any value to them. Please try to make more substantive edits. Thanks!

Comment: @Pekka웃 I'm just trying to be helpful...but still learning the ropes.  I try to add tags that will help others searching for answers come across these posts...I try to avoid editing their content till I feel a bit more comfortable making direct changes.  Is this not the correct way to approach this?

Comment: @NonlinearIdeas tags like "algorithm" or "binaryfiles" don't really add value, and suggested edits are supposed to encompass the *entire* post. Let me see whether I can dig up a guide

Comment: @NonLinearIdeas on tagging, hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging In general, adding a tag is fine but only if it's really *substantial* to the question - for example, when the programming language is missing or the library that's being used. Don't be afraid to also touch everything else you see wrong in the post - spelling errors, grammatical mistakes, et cetera. The only thing that's a hot topic is edits to code in questions, those are deemed taboo because it's too easy to distort the asker's original meaning. Good luck!

Comment: The definition of the as_bytes() function can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46108877/exact-definition-of-as-bytes-function) or in wowofbob's answer. It was not obvious to me that this method was not a standard library method. OP should have clarified...

Comment: @s.r.a can you define as_bytes() and keep_window_open()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## write and read

`write` and `read` methods are used for i/o operations with binary files.

They has the following prototypes:

```
write(memory_block, size);
read(memory_block, size);
```

The `write` writes `size` bytes from `memory_block` to associated file.

The `read`  reads `size` bytes from associated file and writes it to a `memory_block`

For example, in your case,

```
ofs.write(as_bytes(j), sizeof(int));
```

writes bytes of `j` number into a bynary file named `name2`.

You can see more about input and output with files [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/).

### Why you havn't number five in name2 five

You write the bytes of `j` variable to `name2` file in binary i/o mode. Any i/o operation is performed independently of any format considerations in this mode. It don't add carriage return after written data. This means that you can't read the `name2` file and see the five number there.

### Why you have a zero number in name3 file

The reason is because of typo :)

First look at the lines

```
   ifstream ifs(name1.c_str()); // Here I want to read from the ordinary text file (name1).
   ifs >> j; // Now j equals to 5 because name1 contains digit 5.
   ifs.close();
```

And then look at the lines

```
 ifstream ifs1(name2.c_str(), ios::binary); // Here I want to read from that binary file (name2).
 ifs.read(as_bytes(k), sizeof(int)); // Here I hope k becomes 5.
```

You are trying to read bytes from already closed file stream object. Any operation with such objects ends up with error. You can check it out in this way:

```
assert(!ifs.read(as_bytes(k), sizeof(int)));
```

It is possible because `read` returns a mutable reference to `ifs` and `ifs` is convertible to boolean value.

Because of all stuff above in this section, the value of variable `k` stay unchanged.
You can't read from closed file, you can't change the `k` value. Because of this the old
value of `k` is written to the `name3` file.

### Working example

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef char byte;

template<typename T>
byte* as_bytes(T* ptr) {
    return reinterpret_cast<byte*>(ptr);
}

int main()
{

    string
        name1 = "first.txt",
        name2 = "second.bin",
        name3 = "third.txt";

    int j = 0, k = 0;

    // Here I want to read from the ordinary text file (name1).
    ifstream ifs(name1.c_str());
    ifs >> j;
    // Now j equals to 5 because name1 contains digit 5.
    assert(j == 5);
    ifs.close();

    ofstream ofs(name2.c_str(), ios::binary);
    // Here I want to write that j to name2 file in binary mode.
    ofs.write(as_bytes(&j), sizeof(int));                      
    ofs.close();

    // Here I want to read from that binary file (name2).
    ifstream ifs1(name2.c_str(), ios::binary);
    // Here I hope k becomes 5.
    ifs1.read(as_bytes(&k), sizeof(int));


    ofstream ofs1(name3.c_str());
    // Here I want to write that k to name3 file in ordinary text mode.
    ofs1 << k;

    ifs1.close();
    ofs1.close();
}
```