# Exact definition of as_bytes function

Tags: c++

I found this function while reading and I can't find its definition on [CPPreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/)

> programming Principles by Bjarne stroustrup

It is used in this way:

```
ifs.read(as_bytes(x),sizeof(int));`
```

I understand how `read`works but still can you help me with `to_bytes` standard definition.

Comment: http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h

Comment: @tkausl Thanks a ton mate!!!

Comment: In that book, the first thing you do when you aren't sure about something is look in `std_lib_facilities.h` to make sure it isn't hiding in there. He says on page 392 that `as_bytes()` uses C++ features that will be explained in 17.8 and 19.3. yes, a little frustrating but what are ya' gonna do that's the nature of the beast?  :)  Chapter 9  of C++ Without Fear has a nice section on binary file I/O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `as_bytes` function returns the address of the first byte of the argument (so the `read` call will overwrite the object `x`). Therefore in C++11 or later one would write that function as follows:

```
template <class T>
char* as_bytes(T& x) {
    return &reinterpret_cast<char&>(x);
    // or:
    // return reinterpret_cast<char*>(std::addressof(x));
}
```

The version linked in the comments predates C++11. Presumably the reason why Stroustrup converts first to `void*` is because `reinterpret_cast` is not guaranteed to do the right thing in C++03. Note also that the old version will not work correctly for an argument that has an overloaded `&` operator.