# The size of these structs are different in a file but the same in program memory

Tags: c++, c++17, sizeof

Consider the following POD struct:

```
struct MessageWithArray {
    uint32_t raw;
    uint32_t myArray[10];

    //MessageWithArray() : raw(0), myArray{ 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100 } {  };
};
```

Running the following:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

struct MessageWithArray {
    uint32_t raw;
    uint32_t myArray[10];

    //MessageWithArray() : raw(0), myArray{ 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100 } {  };
};

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46108877/exact-definition-of-as-bytes-function
template <class T>
char* as_bytes(T& x) {
    return &reinterpret_cast<char&>(x);
    // or:
    // return reinterpret_cast<char*>(std::addressof(x));
}

int main() {
    MessageWithArray msg = { 0, {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} };
    std::cout << "Size of MessageWithArray struct: " << sizeof(msg) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Is a POD? " << std::is_pod<MessageWithArray>() << std::endl;
    std::ofstream buffer("message.txt");
    buffer.write(as_bytes(msg), sizeof(msg));
    return 0;
}
```

Gives the following output:

> Size of MessageWithArray struct: 44
>
> Is a POD? 1

A hex dump of the "message.txt" file looks like this:

```
00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  01  00  00  00  02  00  00  00
03  00  00  00  04  00  00  00  05  00  00  00  06  00  00  00
07  00  00  00  08  00  00  00  09  00  00  00
```

Now if I uncomment the constructor (so that `MessageWithArray` has a zero-argument constructor), `MessageWithArray` becomes a non-POD struct. Then I use the constructor to initialize instead. This results in the following changes in the code:

```
....
struct MessageWithArray {
    .....

    MessageWithArray() : raw(0), myArray{ 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100 }{  };
};
....
int main(){
    MessageWithArray msg;
    ....
}
```

Running this code, I get:

> Size of MessageWithArray struct: 44
>
> Is a POD? 0

A hex dump of the "message.txt" file looks like this:

```
00  00  00  00  0D  0A  00  00  00  14  00  00  00  1E  00  00
00  28  00  00  00  32  00  00  00  3C  00  00  00  46  00  00
00  50  00  00  00  5A  00  00  00  64  00  00  00
```

Now, I'm not so interested in the actual hex values, what I'm curious about is *why there is one more byte in the non-POD struct dump compared to the POD struct dump, when sizeof() declares they are the same number of bytes*? Is it possible that, because the constructor makes the struct non-POD, that something hidden has been added to the struct? sizeof() should be an accurate compile-time check, correct? Is something possibly avoiding being measured by sizeof()?

**Specifications**: I am running this in an empty project in Visual Studio 2017 version 15.7.5, Microsoft Visual C++ 2017, on a Windows 10 machine.

Intel Core i7-4600M CPU
64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor

**EDIT**: I decided to initialize the struct to avoid Undefined Behaviour, and because the question is still valid with the initialization. Initializing it to a value without 10 preserves the behaviour I observed initially, because the data the array had never contained any 10s (even if it was garbage, and random).

Comment: You should open file in binary mode

Comment: The title doesn't exaclt y match what is going on considering `sizeof` gives you the same value in each run

Comment: Can this post be improved? I'll think of a better title, but it seems difficult now that I know why...

Comment: Title changed! I think I mixed up my own hypothesis about what was going on and the actual situation...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has nothing to do with POD-ness.

Your `ofstream` is opened in text mode (rather than binary mode). On windows it means that `\n` gets converted to `\r\n`.

In the second case there happened to be one `0x0A` (`\n`) byte in the struct, that became `0x0D 0x0A` (`\r\n`). That's why you see an extra byte.

---

Also, using uninitialized variables in the first case leads to undefined behaviour, which is this case didn't manifest itself.

Comment: Shouldn't that happen in both cases then?

Comment: @NathanOliver The contents of the structs are different in those two cases. By accident one of them had `\n` byte, and the other one did not.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think first case suffers from UB because `msg` is used uninitialized.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Shouldn't you add that to the answer then?

Comment: @VTT what is "UB"?

Comment: @Wand Undefined Behavior

Comment: I decided to edit the post and initialize the array, because UB is not something I want to demonstrate, and the question is more focused this way. Initializing it to an array without 10 as a member preserves what I observed in my original post because 10 was never a "garbage" value in the uninitialized array. It also keeps this answer as a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

Other answer explains the problem with writing binary data into stream opened in text mode, however this code is fundamentally wrong. There is no need to dump anything, the proper way to check sizes of those structures and verify that they are equal would be to use `static_assert`:

```
struct MessageWithArray {
    uint32_t raw;
    uint32_t myArray[10];
};

struct NonPodMessageWithArray {
    uint32_t raw;
    uint32_t myArray[10];

    NonPodMessageWithArray() : raw(0), myArray{ 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100 } {}
};

static_assert(sizeof(MessageWithArray) == sizeof(NonPodMessageWithArray));
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yUrBZ01rE53I4lzn)

Comment: I think the reason I titled my post as such is because I somehow felt that non-PODness meant a hidden pointer or something could be added to the struct which would somehow elide sizeof(), hence why I was using the dumps to compare.

Comment: @Wand a hidden pointer is a sign of virtual functions (or virtual inheritance). If you add a virtual method into `NonPodMessageWithArray` then its size will be indeed bigger and static assert will yield a compile-time error.

Comment: yes I mean something like that - I felt non-PODness meant something else could have been added, and that was my thinking in the question. Of course non-PODness doesn't guarantee something has to be added but it also means there is no guarantee something wasn't added...

Comment: I have edited the title because I think the new title better explains my thinking, is more representative of the question, and is more likely to be useful to future users.